# Convert Matrix to Vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have a matrix. I want to get a vector from the matrix as described in example below:

```
Matrix = [ 2  4  5; 
           8  2  13; 
           0  3  1; 
           7  7  7; 
           36 62 72; 
           44 35 26;
           63 11 4;
           9  9  9 ];

vector = [ 2 8 0 4 2 3 5 13 1 7 36 44 63 62 35 11 72 26 4 9];
```

The vector inserts every values from the first three rows from each column. Then It inserts the fourth row value once. Then, the process is repeated same way for the rest of elements in the matrix. How to do this in Matlab?

Comment: What do you think of reshape, with a for loop? Anyway, you should show what you have attempted so far. Do that I and you will have better chance to get help here.

Comment: Your description says you are somehow reordering the elements, but the matrix and the vector contain different elements.

Comment: I tried reshaping the matrix but It doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, there is reordering as described above in the example. The elements in the matrix and the vector are the same. I already checked them in the Matlab Workspace.

Comment: The matrix is 8x3 and the desired output of the vector is 1x20.

Comment: The elements 7 and 9 should be inserted only once in the vector. They are repeated three times in the three columns in the matrix.

Comment: The trick is on the elements reordering. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Dani You have still not provided your attempts. I know what you try to achieve, SO is unforutnately not a code writing service. In case you need a guy to write code, you will need to hire someone. I hint however: A for loop + reshape will work. Only reshape will not. Think of the lines you want to reshape and you will realize that. By editing the question to show your attempts, you may get it opened again. You should also mention that you want to reshape each 3-by-3 matrix, take the first element of the first row and discard 2 element and that it will be repeated for each 4-by-3 submatrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a very specific one. I don't see how this will be of any use to anybody but yourself. 
There is no 'one line solution'.
There are many ways to approach indexing problems, I like to use scalar indexing when possible:

```
Ncolumns = size(Matrix,1);
Nblocks = floor(Ncolumns/4);                                  %number of 4-line blocks (excluding the last block if it is not a full 4-lines)
IndexVector = (1:3)'*ones(1,3) + ones(3,1)*(0:2) * Ncolumns; %this gives 3 lines as specified.
IndexVector = [IndexVector(:); 4];                           %this adds the first element of 4th line, as spec.
IndexVector = IndexVector*ones(1,Nblocks)+ones(10,1)*(0:Nblocks-1)*4; %this repeats the above for rest of blocks.
IndexVector = IndexVector(:)';                               %make row vector

vector=Matrix(IndexVector);

if mod(Ncolumns,4)                               %this deals with the last partial block
   subMat=Matrix(Nblocks*4+1:end,1:3);
   vector=[vector subMat(:)']; 
end
```